# How to pass node value to custom msxsl:script function?

Tags: xslt, jscript, msxsl

I have a custom function in my XSLT document like so:

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="custom">
function uriencode(string) {
     return encodeURIComponent(string);
</msxsl:script>
```

When I try passing it the value of a node like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="urlp" select="Path/To/Some[@attr='condition']/Node" />
<xsl:value-of select="custom:uriencode($urlp)" />
```

It gives me this result:

```
MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathSelectionIterator
```

So I gather that I haven't passed the actual value of the `Node` to my function, but how do I do that? Or alternatively, retrieve the value of the node from the object that's being passed to my function?

Comment: How are you invoking the XSLT transform? In C#? Could you show the code if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass in an XSLT/XPath string which is treated in the "script" function as a .NET String then use `<xsl:value-of select="custom:uriencode(string($urlp))" />`.

If you want to solve it on the .NET side then call `MoveNext()` e.g.

```
function encode(nodeIterator) {
  if (nodeIterator.MoveNext()) {
    return encodeURIComponent(nodeIterator.Current.Value);
  }
  else {
    return '';
  }
}
```